# Receive nested complex json via retrofit2 and gson

Tags: android, lazy-loading, retrofit2

In my android demo app, I want to receive json via retrofit2 and gson. json have some images ( on which I wanna do lazy loading ) and nested json with different structure also. So how can I proceed?

Any help appreciated... :)

Comment: Posting an extract of the json is a start.

Comment: Yeah sure. You can see extracted json ftom the https://www.reddit.com/r/funny.json

Comment: And what have you come up with so far for the parsing structure?Post your POJOS or use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: ok I will try to use jsonschema2pojo.org

Comment: Hey thanks for above link. I solved my problem. Actually my json response not having uniform structure. Thats why I came across this problem.